# When using Flip Fluids and enable whitewater any Foam Spray or bubble appear as these icospheres

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I have a problem when enabling the whitewater in the Flip Fluids addon. I get these big icospheres that I don't know how to fix. I've changed a lot of domain settings and it doesn't make any difference when rendering. Can someone help?

[image: How the foam, spray and bubbles appear when whitewater is enabled]

Answer (score 1):

In the domain FLIP Fluid Display Settings panel, you can set the scale of the whitewater particles used for rendering.

[image: FLIP Fluid Display Settings]